# Ruby Rerun my script

Tags: ruby, loops

I want my ruby code to rerun my code if the user asks it. To do this is I provided a question at the end asking if the user wants to continue it. I want it so that if gets.chomp() = yes it reruns the program.

I was thinking of making it a loop but am unsure of how to go with this approach either.

```html
require './codes/AlName.rb'
require './codes/UserName.rb'

system 'cls'



    puts("What do you want me to do?")
    command = gets.chomp()

    commands = [
        "time",
        "done",
        "chat",
        "help",
    ]

    #display time (Time.now)
    if command == commands[0]
        puts(Time.now)
    end 

    if command == commands[1]
        exit
    end

    if command == commands[3]
        puts(commands)
    end


    #chat
    if command == commands[2]
        system 'cls'
        puts("Hello " + UserName)
    end

    #pauses system
    sleep 10
    puts("Do you want to continue?")
    Response = get.chomp()
    if Response == "yes"
        (rerun program here)
    end

    if Response == "no"
        exit
    end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of doing this is running everything inside of a loop. I am assuming you would like to re-run the code every time. I also refactored for you into a switch statement.

```
command = gets.chomp.downcase
until command == "no"
    case command
    when command[0]
        puts Time.now
    when command[1]
        exit
    when command[2]
        system 'cls'
        puts("Hello " + UserName)
    when command[3]
        puts commands
    end
end
```

If you do not want to re-run the code every time, I would put the code you would like to re-run in a function.

```
def repeat
    command = gets.chomp.downcase
    case command
    when command[0]
        puts Time.now
    when command[1]
        exit
    when command[2]
        system 'cls'
        puts("Hello " + UserName)
    when command[3]
        puts commands
    when "no"
        repeat
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I would not have thought of using until's

Comment: No problem! I'm sure you'll run into the design pattern in the future. Plus when I first learned ruby using `until` and `unless` was a little counterintuitive, but after writing ruby code for a while it'll become second nature.

Answer (score 0):

See, you can put the Response in the while loop and keep it continuing it till the value of Response variable is yes.

```
require './codes/AlName.rb'
require './codes/UserName.rb'

system 'cls'

Response = 'yes'
commands = %w(time done chat help)

 while(Response != 'No'){
  command = gets.chomp

  puts Time.now if commands.include?('time')
  exit if commands.include?('done')
  puts commands if commands.include?('help')

  if commands.include?('chat')
    system('cls')
    puts "Hello #{UserName}" #take this as input
  end

  sleep 10 
  Response = get.chomp
  exit if Response == 'no'
 }
```